# ACPI error messages during boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

That's what I have:

```
[0.392600] ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD.STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
[0.395125] ACPI Error: Aborting Method \_SB.PAGD.STA due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psargs-529)
[0.462711] ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD.STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
[0.462733] ACPI Error: Aborting Method \_SB.PAGD.STA due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psargs-529)
[0.520375] ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD.STA._OSI], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
[0.520401] ACPI Error: Aborting Method \_SB.PAGD.STA due to previous error  (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psargs-529)
[0.710064] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
[2.759141] tpm tpm0: tpm_try_transmit: send(): error -62
[2.759176] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling inst
[3.708294] ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD.STA._
[3.708385] ACPI Error: Aborting Method \_SB.PAGD.STA due to previous error
[3.734529] ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PAGD.STA._
[3.734567] ACPI Error: Aborting Method \_SB.PAGD.STA due to previous error
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 283295/61022208 files, 9573235/244059136 blocks
```

[Update 1]

- SATA was already set as AHCI
- I have turn TPM off
- I don’t know how to update BIOS on linux Could you send me a link with more info?
- I can try moving to a newer release but first I want to share what the manufacturer has told me:

I was asking how to boot into the BIOS and they asked me why. They told me how to do so but they recommended me to ignore the error messages, they said as long as I can boot into Ubuntu I shouldn’t care and they believe it’s due to the new hardware and in future releases everything should work fine.

I can boot into Ubuntu but I just wanted to know if I can or must fix that

I have a moove2-15 from Vant PC. I has an Intel Core i5-1035G1 with BIOS v1.07.04TSP1

Comment: If it is during boot the best you can most likely do is take a pic and then type the text into the question you are asking.

Comment: You should see them in `dmesg`.

Comment: please also add: brand, make, model of the machine and the bios version in use.

Comment: Nothing really happened with OS. Everything is going normally.

Answer (score 10):

Generic answer: this is a normal error when hardware is too new for the kernel. The BIOS is reporting info the kernel did not expect when probing it.

Things to test/check:

- In BIOS, System Configuration, SATA options, switch from RAID to AHCI. This is a common one so might be the answer for you.
- This `tpm tpm0 tpm_try_transmit: send(): error -62` is also important. [Trusted platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module). There is something related to TPM in your BIOS that your kernel does not accept. See if you can turn TPM off in BIOS.
- Update BIOS
- Install a newer kernel (newer Ubuntu release)

If those all fail or are not possible: file a bugreport or add yourself to a bug about this.

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I sent the laptop to the technical support department. The said nothing was wrong but the problem was still there after some time of use.

The solution was update to Ubuntu 21.10, no more issues, everything goes fine. Ubuntu 21.04 still had the same issue.

Comment: This is not a Solution, this is brute force method of removing a problem.
You could also install Windows, or Fedora.

Comment: During installation check the options to download updates while installing Ubuntu and connect to a wireless network by providing the credentials. That solves the problem in Ubuntu 20.04.4 lts

Comment: Lot of people have suggested me to try Fedora but it's not a solution, although I think I'll try it. I'll check also the clean installation with Internet connection. It's weird because the problems appeared after a clean installation made by the technical support department of the manufacturer