# When I turn on my desktop, every time showing some error [ Ubuntu 22.04 ]

Tags: boot, 22.04

I am a new user of Ubuntu. Recently I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish). The problem is when I turn on my pc every time there show some errors at booting time. I mentioned the problems down below:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM.AFN7], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

Why do these errors occur and how to solve them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367947/acpi-error-messages-during-boot)

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. What video card/display do you have? Nvidia? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema My computer motherboard model is ASRock B450 Steel Legend and the processor is AMD Ryzen 3 3200G. I don't have a video card. The command gave the output "P3.70".

Comment: @FoyezNaeem There's a much newer BIOS available at https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/b450m%20steel%20legend/#BIOS1. Read ALL of the instructions! See the **CPU Support List** to determine your CPU model... I think you have Pinnacle. Have good backups before updating the BIOS.