# Screen stucked at Grub screen with error ACPI Error

Tags: boot, shutdown, grub-efi

Info:

Laptop: Acer Nitro 5 an515-42
  CPU: AMD Ryzen
  OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Here is what happened. I started my laptop normally as usual and did my college work. I watched some videos about Kodi. I installed Kodi using Flatpak. I opened the Kodi app, and pressed Esc to exit. It gave me options like Shutdown, Restart etc. I pressed Restart then... my laptop screen started flickering, and during boot it shows the following error:

```
ACPI Bios error (bug): AE_NOT_Found
```

[image: Photo of error]

I got scared because I read somewhere that Linux Bios  can cause problems. I googled and found that this is a normal problem. But none of the keys work when this error comes. Enter key doesn't work inside GRUB menu.

I force shut down by holding power button and power on the system again
Then under Advanced options I choose the first option that is some kernel option.(because after force shut down the arrow keys works)

Then it boots...

Now I've to do this every time.
I don't understand how to fix this issue.

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367947/acpi-error-messages-during-boot)

Comment: Please add what distro you are using, your hardware specs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your hardware is too new for the kernel.

Install a newer version of your Linux distro, so you don't have to choose the kernel every time.

OR

You could update your kernel (if you have any updates).

Do that by:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Tried this one also didn't get any success so finally went back to Windows 10. I'm happy that I enjoyed Ubuntu for full month without any issues. I wish this problem will resolve soon so that I'll try to come back to Linux again hopefully. But for now Linux is not for me because it gives me so much headache since last week.